# parsing xml with same tags in perl

Tags: xml, perl

How to parse the following xml fields using  XML::Simple in perl

```
<SelectedSections>
  <Section Name="A_1" />
  <Section Name="B_1" />
</SelectedSections>
```

so that I can have output as

```
A_1
B_1
```

I tried something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::Simple;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
my $file1 = 'testxml';
my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1);
print $data->{SelectedSections}->{Section-> 'Name'} ,"\n";
```

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried so far? Maybe you were already really close to the solution and just missed some minor detail – we can help you make it work. That said, `XML::Simple` is deprecated, because it is anything but simple. Even [its own documentation says so](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE).

Comment: I have tried something like this
   
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use XML::Simple;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use Data::Dumper;
    my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
    my $file1 = 'testxml';
    my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1);
    print $data->{SelectedSections}->{Section-> 'Name'} ,"\n";

And why is XML::Simple deprecated; what are the other alternatives to parse xml using perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `XML::Simple` you can do it as below

```
my $xml = XML::Simple->new;
my $file1 = 'test.xml';
my $data = $xml->XMLin($file1);

print(Dumper($data));   

# If you print this dumper you will see that the 'SelectedSections' is not in $data

my @sections = @{$data->{Section}};

foreach my $s (@sections) {
    print($s->{Name} . "\n");
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Section' => [
                       {
                         'Name' => 'A_1'
                       },
                       {
                         'Name' => 'B_1'
                       }
                     ]
        };
A_1
B_1
```

Comment: Thank you!! @DA14 for doing it through XML::Simple

Answer (score 1):

If unsure what the data structure created by your XML is, just dump it. In our case, we get this:

```
{ Section => [{ Name => "A_1" }, { Name => "B_1" }] }
```

So to print out the first name, we'd have to do

```
say $data->{Section}[0]{Name};
```

To print out all sections, we could do

```
for my $section (@{ $data->{Section} }) {
    say $section->{Name};
}
```

---

The problem with XML::Simple is that it's very difficult to predict the data structure created by a piece of XML. Other XML interfaces like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML) are more consistent (`XML::LibXML` uses the standardized DOM interface). For example, I'd solve this problem like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => "filename.xml");
for my $name ($xml->findnodes('/SelectedSections/Section/@Name')) {
    say $name->value;
}
```

The string passed to the `findnodes` method is an XPath expression which can be used to easily access parts in even rather complex XML documents.

Comment: Thanks @amon; I will try using  XML::LibXML; Its always nice to have alternatives. Thank you.